# React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually when hosted in render.com

Tags: reactjs, webpack, render, bundler, vite

How to work with react-router with website hosted on render.com

my react-router is

```
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path={"/"} element={<ProductsList />} />
                <Route exact path="/divisionSection" element={<Home />} />
                {/* <Route path="/addDivision/:type" element={<AddDivision />} /> */}
                <Route path="/addDivision" element={<AddDivision />} />
                <Route path={"/editProduct/:objectId"} element={<AddProduct />} />
                <Route path="/productsList" element={<ProductsList />} />
                <Route path="/addProduct" element={<AddProduct />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
```

Clearly this wont work

[image]

When i type **`https://cakeservice.onrender.com/productsList`** It will show not found or `index.html` because i had set it that way , but i dont way `index.html` for all , i want according to my react-router.

##### My tries:

1. Using `webpack`, but i am stuck in the part where you load the bootstrap , and i am not finding solution.

Just i know if i use webpack i can use:

```
devServer: {
   historyApiFallback: true,
   contentBase: './',
   hot: true
},
```

2. I tried using `vite.js`, i couldn't set it up with already exisiting vite project and i dont know if it supports fallback methodology.

An answer or alternative or resource to look into would be great. Please

Answer (score 0):

In a React app, you have only one index.html file which renders every page inside itself. For that reason, we are calling this kind of websites SPA(Single Page Application). On the server side, you always need to redirect your page to your root folder which contains index.html.

On the other hand, I think you do not need to redirect some route to a directory in src/ folder. React-router-dom is the library that will handles this routing for you.

Comment: How can you post a comment as a answer ? , where is answer is this ?

Comment: @NewUser, I guess my answer will help many others. Thanks.